# AWS .NET PutObjectRequest using wrong host

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, runtime-error

I am using the .NET library for Amazon Web Services for an application that uploads images to an Amazon S3 bucket. It is used in an internal service of an ASP.NET 4.5 application. The NuGet package name is AWSSDK and its version is the latest (as of writing) stable: 2.3.54.2

When I attempt to use the PutObject method on the PutObjectRequest object (to upload the image blob), it throws an exception and complains that the hostname is wrong.

```
var accessKey = Config.GetValue("AWSAccessKey");
var secretKey = Config.GetValue("AWSSecretKey");
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, config))
{
            var request = new PutObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = Config.GetValue("PublicBucket");
            request.Key = newFileName;
            request.InputStream = resizedImage;
            request.AutoCloseStream = false;
            using (var uploadTaskResult = client.PutObject(request))
            {
                using (var uploadStream = uploadTaskResult.ResponseStream)
                {
                    uploadStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var resultStr = new StreamReader(uploadStream).ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
}
```

The exception details are as follows:

```
Fatal unhandled exception in Web API component: System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'images.ourcompany.com.http'
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.getRequestStreamCallback[T](IAsyncResult result)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.endOperation[T](IAsyncResult result)
   at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.EndPutObject(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Tracks.Application.Services.Bp.BpTemplateService.UploadImage(Byte[] image, String fileName) in ...
```

I have tried to debug this in VS by stepping through the code but AWSSDK doesn't come with debug symbols. It should be noted that the remote host name (or bucket name as I think Amazon calls them) is images.ourcompany.com (not our real company's name!). I have checked the value of `Config.GetValue("PublicBucket")` and it is indeed images.ourcompany.com. At this stage I have exhausted my limited knowledge about Amazon S3 and have no theories about what causes the exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add region endpoint or/and set ServiceUrl to establish connection to AmazonS3 check the similar question below:
[Coping folder inside AmazonS3 Bucket (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028861/coping-folder-inside-amazons3-bucket-c)
[Upload images on Amazon S3. source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005716/upload-images-on-amazon-s3-source-code)

```
 AmazonS3Config cfg = new AmazonS3Config();  
    cfg.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.SAEast1;//your region Endpoint
    string butcketName = "yourBucketName";
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("your access key",
     "your secret key", cfg);
     PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
                    {
                        BucketName = _bucket,
                        InputStream = stream,
                        Key = fullName
                    };

                    s3Client.PutObject(request);

or

    AmazonS3Config asConfig = new AmazonS3Config()
    {
        ServiceURL = "http://irisdb.s3-ap-southeast2.amazonaws.com/",
        RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2
    };
```

Comment: Where did you get that service URL?