# How can I Copy a folder inside an AmazonS3 Bucket using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy one folder, with all existing files inside it, to another folder inside AmazonS3's same Bucket.

I can copy one object, but what I need is to copy a folder with all its files into another Folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the example to copy folder inside AmazonS3 Bucket Which works for me.
For more details you can check this [link](http://derpturkey.com/copy-a-folder-in-amazons3-using-the-c-api/)

```
  public bool CopyFolderInsideS3Bucket(string source, string destination)
        {
            var strippedSource = source;
            var strippedDestination = destination;

            // process source
            if (strippedSource.StartsWith("/"))
                strippedSource = strippedSource.Substring(1);
            if (strippedSource.EndsWith("/"))
                strippedSource = source.Substring(0, strippedSource.Length - 1);

            var sourceParts = strippedSource.Split('/');
            var sourceBucket = sourceParts[0];

            var sourcePrefix = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = 1; i < sourceParts.Length; i++)
            {
                sourcePrefix.Append(sourceParts[i]);
                sourcePrefix.Append("/");
            }

            // process destination
            if (strippedDestination.StartsWith("/"))
                strippedDestination = destination.Substring(1);
            if (strippedDestination.EndsWith("/"))
                strippedDestination = destination.Substring(0, strippedDestination.Length - 1);

            var destinationParts = strippedDestination.Split('/');
            var destinationBucket = destinationParts[0];

            var destinationPrefix = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = 1; i < destinationParts.Length; i++)
            {
                destinationPrefix.Append(destinationParts[i]);
                destinationPrefix.Append("/");
            }

            var listObjectsResult = client.ListObjects(new ListObjectsRequest(){ 
                BucketName = sourceBucket,
                Prefix = sourcePrefix.ToString(),
                Delimiter = "/"});

            // copy each file
            foreach (var file in listObjectsResult.S3Objects)
            {
                var request = new CopyObjectRequest();
                request.SourceBucket = Settings.BucketName;
                request.SourceKey = file.Key;
                request.DestinationBucket = destinationBucket;
                request.DestinationKey = destinationPrefix + file.Key.Substring(sourcePrefix.Length);
                request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
                var response = (CopyObjectResponse)client.CopyObject(request);
            }

            // copy subfolders
            foreach (var folder in listObjectsResult.CommonPrefixes)
            {
                var actualFolder = folder.Substring(sourcePrefix.Length);
                actualFolder = actualFolder.Substring(0, actualFolder.Length - 1);
                CopyFolderInsideS3Bucket(strippedSource + "/" + actualFolder, strippedDestination + "/" + actualFolder);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use S3DirectoryInfo class  in the amazon version 3.1.5 .net 3.5 this class copyTo method.

I used the following example C# code to copy from NTFS file path to AmazonS3 with C# .net 3.5 and amazon version 3.1.5:

```
   BasicAWSCredentials basicCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("your access key", "your secret key");
            AmazonS3Config configurationClient = new AmazonS3Config();
            configurationClient.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1;
            try
            {
                using (AmazonS3Client clientConnection = new AmazonS3Client(basicCredentials, configurationClient))
                {
                    S3DirectoryInfo source = new S3DirectoryInfo(clientConnection, "sourcebucketname", "sourcefolderkey");
                    S3DirectoryInfo target = new S3DirectoryInfo(clientConnection, "sourcebucketname", "destinationfolderkey");
                    source.CopyTo(target);

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
```