# Upload images on Amazon S3. source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images on Amazon s3. I have tried different source codes but no vain.I am stuck to differentiate b/w IAmazonClient, Amazons3 objects etc.
can anyone give me example and direct me how can i upload images on s3.I am developing REST service that can capture images and upload on amazon s3.

- My bucket is in Sydney Australia.
- http://irisdb.s3apsoutheast2.
  amazonaws.com/
- accesskey = "xxxxxxxx"
- secretKey = "cxxxxxxxxx"
- Endpoint: irisdb.s3websiteapsoutheast2.
  amazonaws.com

  ```
      string accessKey = "xxxx";
      string secretKey = "mxxxxx";
      string bucketName = "irisdb"; // Set to a bucket you create              
      // Create S3 service client.            

      BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
      AmazonS3Config asConfig = new AmazonS3Config()
      {
          ServiceURL = "http://irisdb.s3-ap-southeast2.amazonaws.com/",
          ServiceEndPoint = "irisdb.s3-website-ap-southeast2.amazonaws.com" //error here (cannot convert string to endpoints)
      };

      AmazonS3Client client2 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials, asConfig);
      ListBucketsResponse response = client2.ListBuckets();
  ```

I know i need to provide Amazon.Endpoints.ap-southeast-2 in serviceEndPoint but "ap-southeast-2" not exist in the definition of Amazon.EndPoint
Please help

Comment: What did you tried? [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html) for example?

Comment: you can see 
[http://bradoyler.com/post/3614362044/uploading-an-image-with-aws-sdk-for-net-c]
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814972/how-to-upload-a-file-to-amazon-s3-super-easy-using-c-sharp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the solution by myself.

```
AmazonS3Config asConfig = new AmazonS3Config()
{
    ServiceURL = "http://irisdb.s3-ap-southeast2.amazonaws.com/",
    RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2
};
```

Making RegionalEndPoints correct. my application run like a charm. Thanks for everyone.